# recursion(python) help please

Tags: python, recursion

I'm new to programming world, and I'm struggling with recursion.

This is my code, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work :(

```
enter_number = input("enter 'x' value: ")
def g(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    elif x == 1:
        return 2
    else:
        return g(x−1) + g(x−3) + g(x−4)

print(g(enter_number))
```

thank you

Comment: what about the cases for x == 2 and x == 3?

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565674/implement-recursion-using-one-recursive-call

Comment: You're not handling 2 and 3 in your end cases. Also, if you are new to programming, I'd recommend you stay out of recursion for a while till you're comfortable with the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `g` function doesn't handle inputs `2` and `3`.